# KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE BSOD Error

Tags: windows-8.1, bsod

I have been getting this error on my laptop and I am getting absolutely sick of it now.

I have downloaded many fixes from Microsoft websites but no joy.

If I google it, I get 1000 different possible reasons for this issue, Is there any one stop solution for this issue?

I have updated all of my drivers, Scanned disk for any issues, Scanned Memory for any issues and found nothing.

I get two errors simultaneously `KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE` and `FIX IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`.

First it would restart the laptop once I get the error, but now it just freezes and I have to power shutdown and start the machine.

**Laptop Specs:**

```
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702 CPU @ 2.20GHz
RAM:       32GB
SSD:       120GB
HHD:       1TB
OS:        Windows 8.1 64 bit
```

**Error Screen Shot**

[image]

Comment: You used MemTestx86 and let it ran through multiple times overnight?  This error is connected to a bad memory modual

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump.